# Chrome html5 form validation in a jQuery pop-up dialog

Tags: jquery, html, validation

This is very similar to [this old, unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330467/jquery-dialog-form-with-html5-validation).

I have a jQuery dialog box that has a form embedded in it. The rest of the forms on my site make use of html5 browser capabilities, so I want the error messages for required form elements to be the same in the pop-up form. Short of writing my own validation to mimic the formatting of browser validation pop-ups, can anyone think of a way to get Chrome to do the validation of inside the jQuery dialog box?

Here's the code. The html5 `required` attribute is appearing on the element and it's being marked as user-error, it's just not being recognized by Chrome.

```
var form = dialog.find('form');
if (!$('#formElement')[0].checkValidity()) {
    if (element.prop('type') != 'submit') {
        form.find(':submit').first().trigger('click');
    }
    return;
}
$('#action').trigger('click');
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one tips & trick.

> 1. HTML5 validation is not good in all cases and can fail.
> 2. With complex websites with many popups, dynamc forms etc. you can't use only HTML5 validation because you don't have control.
> 3. Crome, Mozilla, Safari, Opera, Explorer (Edge), mobile browsers (CM, UC, Dolphin, Rocket, Yandex, Puffin, Brave, Crome...) work different and some times you need to do same things for each browsers on some other way because of it's rules and supports. Many of these browsers are on WebKit but not work same.
> 4. For your project is better to use some jQuery library for validation or simple write by own.

From my side, made dialog, fill with form, validate that form with jQuery and on particular events switch content, close dialog, open new dialog or wathever you want. Is faster and better.

Comment: Thanks so much, Ivijan! I thought this might be the case, just wanted to see if there was some work-around. Much appreciated!